# TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, long found (Flask app)

Tags: unicode, flask

This is my views.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Blueprint, request, render_template, flash, g, session, redirect, url_for
from flask.ext.login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from app import db
from app.users.models import User
from app.news.models import News, NewsImg
from app.main.forms import LoginForm

mod = Blueprint('main', __name__, url_prefix='/')

@mod.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username, password=password).first()
        if user is None:
            flash('Incorrect login or password', 'error')
            return redirect("/")
        login_user(user)
        return redirect("/")
    news = News.query.order_by(News.putdate.desc()).limit(3)
    return render_template("main/main.html", 
        news= news,
        form = form)
```

After authorization (Flask-Login) in logs an error:
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, long found

On the local machine it works, the problem only on the server

> [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015] [error] [client 81.24.82.162] mod_wsgi
>   (pid=59836): Exception occurred processing WSGI script
>   '/home/users/s/sadwolf/domains/e-dag.com/dad.wsgi'., referer: url [Fri
>   Feb 06 10:58:01 2015] [error] [client 81.24.82.162] Traceback (most
>   recent call last):, referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015] [error]
>   [client 81.24.82.162]   File
>   "/home/users/s/sadwolf/virtualenv/dagavtodor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1836, in **call**, referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015]
>   [error] [client 81.24.82.162]     return self.wsgi_app(environ,
>   start_response), referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015] [error]
>   [client 81.24.82.162]   File
>   "/home/users/s/sadwolf/virtualenv/dagavtodor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1820, in wsgi_app, referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015]
>   [error] [client 81.24.82.162]     response =
>   self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e)), referer: url [Fri Feb 06
>   10:58:01 2015] [error] [client 81.24.82.162]   File
>   "/home/users/s/sadwolf/virtualenv/dagavtodor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1403, in handle_exception, referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01
>   2015] [error] [client 81.24.82.162]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value,
>   tb), referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015] [error] [client
>   81.24.82.162]   File "/home/users/s/sadwolf/virtualenv/dagavtodor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1817, in wsgi_app, referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015]
>   [error] [client 81.24.82.162]     response =
>   self.full_dispatch_request(), referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015]
>   [error] [client 81.24.82.162]   File
>   "/home/users/s/sadwolf/virtualenv/dagavtodor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1477, in full_dispatch_request, referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01
>   2015] [error] [client 81.24.82.162]     rv =
>   self.handle_user_exception(e), referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015]
>   [error] [client 81.24.82.162]   File
>   "/home/users/s/sadwolf/virtualenv/dagavtodor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1381, in handle_user_exception, referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01
>   2015] [error] [client 81.24.82.162]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value,
>   tb), referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015] [error] [client
>   81.24.82.162]   File "/home/users/s/sadwolf/virtualenv/dagavtodor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1475, in full_dispatch_request, referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01
>   2015] [error] [client 81.24.82.162]     rv = self.dispatch_request(),
>   referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015] [error] [client 81.24.82.162] 
>   File
>   "/home/users/s/sadwolf/virtualenv/dagavtodor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1461, in dispatch_request, referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01
>   2015] [error] [client 81.24.82.162]     return
>   self.view_functionsrule.endpoint, referer: url [Fri
>   Feb 06 10:58:01 2015] [error] [client 81.24.82.162]   File
>   "/home/users/s/sadwolf/prj/dad/app/main/views.py", line 17, in main,
>   referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015] [error] [client 81.24.82.162] 
>   user = User.query.filter_by(username=username,
>   password=password).first(), referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015]
>   [error] [client 81.24.82.162]   File
>   "/home/users/s/sadwolf/virtualenv/dagavtodor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py",
>   line 2367, in first, referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015] [error]
>   [client 81.24.82.162]     ret = list(self[0:1]), referer: url [Fri Feb
>   06 10:58:01 2015] [error] [client 81.24.82.162]   File
>   "/home/users/s/sadwolf/virtualenv/dagavtodor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py",
>   line 2228, in **getitem**, referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015]
>   [error] [client 81.24.82.162]     return list(res), referer: url [Fri
>   Feb 06 10:58:01 2015] [error] [client 81.24.82.162]   File
>   "/home/users/s/sadwolf/virtualenv/dagavtodor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py",
>   line 73, in instances, referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015] [error]
>   [client 81.24.82.162]     rows = [process[0](row, None) for row in
>   fetch], referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015] [error] [client
>   81.24.82.162]   File "/home/users/s/sadwolf/virtualenv/dagavtodor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py",
>   line 455, in _instance, referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015]
>   [error] [client 81.24.82.162]     populate_state(state, dict_, row,
>   isnew, only_load_props), referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015]
>   [error] [client 81.24.82.162]   File
>   "/home/users/s/sadwolf/virtualenv/dagavtodor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py",
>   line 305, in populate_state, referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015]
>   [error] [client 81.24.82.162]     populator(state, dict_, row),
>   referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015] [error] [client 81.24.82.162] 
>   File
>   "/home/users/s/sadwolf/virtualenv/dagavtodor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py",
>   line 169, in fetch_col, referer: url [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015]
>   [error] [client 81.24.82.162]     dict_[key] = row[col], referer: url
>   [Fri Feb 06 10:58:01 2015] [error] [client 81.24.82.162] TypeError:
>   expected string or Unicode object, long found, referer: url

Comment: What server are you using? Also can you show the full stack trace if you have one?

Comment: added full stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Please exchange all your models':

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.xxx
```

or

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.xxx
```

to unicode methods like:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.xxx)
```

Because you may shows a `long` type or `null`/`None` type for your model, the `__repr__` and `__str__` does not support these type.

`__unicode__()` take effect.

**update**: data in your locale may not be the same type with your server' data.So this error does not appear on your local machine.